# How to check that multiple values are not equal in VBA?

Tags: vba

I want to print a list of eight numbers to the worksheet, but only if they are all unique.

An ideal code would be something along the lines of

```
If a <> b <> c Then
```

Rather than

```
If a <> b And a <> c And b <> c Then
```

Is this possible, given that the values are called from an array using the code following:

```
Cells(2, 8) = numarr(i)
Cells(2, 9) = numarr(j)
Cells(2, 10) = numarr(k)
Cells(2, 11) = numarr(l)
Cells(3, 8) = numarr(m)
Cells(3, 9) = numarr(n)
Cells(3, 10) = numarr(o)
Cells(3, 11) = numarr(p)
```

Thanks!

Comment: One very quick way would be to add up all the numbers: `a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h=sumtotal`, then compare `sumtotal` with `a*8`. Basically, `if (a*8) = sumtotal then all_numbers_are_equal`. Probably quicker than a big logical statement. (and by the way, your first `If` statement is not proper syntax and will not compile.)

Comment: Yeah I knew that the first statement wouldn't work, that was supposed to be a demonstration of what I was aiming to do. The solution to add all the numbers up is really helpful, that should solve my problem very easily! Like you said, much quicker than a large series of logical statements!

Comment: @PeterT - That doesn't work for finding either all unique numbers or finding out if they are all the same.  Consider (in order of a-h): `6, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 4, 10 -->  (6*8) = 6+7+7+5+5+4+4+10`.   Or all unique numbers: `6, 1, 8, 5, 10, 2, 9, 7 --> (6*8) = 6+1+8+5+10+2+9+7`.

Comment: And here I thought I was being clever. @Comintern, you're perfectly right of course. I added another potential answer below to satisfy my need to at least put out a complete and correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

The quick and dirty way to do this is with a Dictionary, which requires a unique key.  Just keep dumping numbers in from your array until you hit one that's already in the Dictionary.  Just make it into a function and pass your array to it:

```
Private Function AllUnique(incoming As Variant) As Boolean

    If Not IsArray(incoming) Then Err.Raise 13

    Dim candidates As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set candidates = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(incoming) To UBound(incoming)
        If candidates.Exists(incoming(index)) Then Exit Function
        candidates.Add incoming(index), index
    Next index

    AllUnique = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to throw in the direct comparison method:

```
Public Function AreEqual(ParamArray values() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, N As Long
    Dim x As Double
    N = UBound(values) + 1
    For i = 1 To N - 1
        x = values(i - 1)
        For j = i + 1 To N
            If values(j - 1) <> x Then
                AreEqual = False
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    AreEqual = True
End Function
```

To be used as

```
If AreEqual(num1,num2,num3,...) then
   ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation of the `Collection` answer given above by @ja72, this function should be able to take any set of simple values of any type and determine if they're all identical or not. (The exception to this being the fourth test line for Strings, in which the `Collection` key is not case-sensitive.) I'm taking advantage of the hashing algorithm for adding keys to a `Collection` to ensure unique-ness.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print AllValuesIdentical(14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14) 'true
    Debug.Print AllValuesIdentical(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5)             'false
    Debug.Print AllValuesIdentical("go", "go", "go", "go")             'true
    Debug.Print AllValuesIdentical("go", "go", "go", "GO")             'also true
    Debug.Print AllValuesIdentical(283.14, 283.14, 283.14)             'true
End Sub

Function AllValuesIdentical(ParamArray vals() As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim uniqueCheck As Collection
    Dim val As Variant
    Set uniqueCheck = New Collection
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each val In vals
        uniqueCheck.Add val, CStr(val)
    Next val
    If uniqueCheck.Count = 1 Then
        AllValuesIdentical = True
    Else
        AllValuesIdentical = False
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set uniqueCheck = Nothing
End Function
```